# How to deal with new client for a IT project?

Tags: startup, entrepreneurship

I am software engineer in India with 10+ years experience. I never deal any client directly. I quit my job and now trying for a startup, for this I made a small IT tech team. I approach many peoples through LinkedIn finally one Australian client give me response take my technical test and interview and he seems interested. He share a brief for a project for 10K USD for this he ask me to give him 1500 USD as security amount, and I need to sign an agreement as well. Do I need to give him money? or what is the right way to make dealing securely.?

Answer (score 15):

> he ask me to give him 1500 USD as security amount

Run a mile. Now. This is a scam.

Comment: How to identify genuine clients???

Comment: That's way outside the scope of a The Workplace question, but they sure as anything don't ask _you_ to pay _them_ money. That's the wrong way round.

Comment: @AmitShakya A genuine client may be willing to give _you_ a down payment on the contract. Never will they ask you to pay.

Comment: Genuine clients won't ask you to pay them.

Comment: Well I that client was asking for money as security amount. Client ask me I am new for him if I finish job on time next time we can continue without any security amount, but I quit.